# Blank page when serving my app (Vue Router 4 - Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli, vuejs3

I have made the first `npm run build` to take my first big Vue3 application to a real-world server test drive.

So I got the files, uploaded them into my VPS, and surprise: The server only recognizes the route paths if I navigate through clicks.

If I happen to reload the page or navigate directly to an URL, the browser throws an error. I have added the code referred here: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html to my `.htaccess` file (I'm using apache on Centos 7
and I'm using CWP), but the problem persists, the only difference is that instead of throwing an error, it just gets stuck in the `index.html` page, but without rendering any content whatsoever.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Please check my code below regarding the implementation of Vue Router 4.

I am defining everything in `main.js` file, like so:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router"
import Page from "./views/Page.vue"
import Content from "./views/Content.vue"
import BaseSection from "./components/BaseSection.vue"

//ROUTER
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [{
            path: "/",
            name: "Home",
            component: Page,
            meta: {
                title: 'Home'
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/docs/1.0/:title",
            component: Content,
            name: "docs"
        }
    ],
    scrollBehavior(to) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return {
                el: to.hash,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            }
        }
    }
});

app.use(router);
```

Any idea or suggestion? I'm going crazy.

thank you.

Regards,
T.

Comment: hi. when you view source of the blank page, what do you see?  what happens when you click/follow the .js / .css links from there?

Comment: I see just the standard VueJS index.html code. When I try to follow the .css file links it just takes me to the index.html again, however, the address in the address bar changes to the name of the route I was plus the name of the .css file (example: /docs/1.0/css/chunk-vendors.e0a049f6.css ---- where /docs/1.0/ is the actual route)

Comment: This comment makes it sound like the app is being served from */docs/1.0/* rather than the domain root.  Is that right?

Comment: Hmmm. I agree with your answer. But the thing is that all the content was uploaded to the domain root. How can it assume that path? Where can I change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blank page error usually happens when serving the app from somewhere other than the domain root.  In that case, the Vue CLI has to be configured accordingly. Modfiy *vue.config.js* in the project root (create it if it doesn't exist):

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/docs/1.0/'  // This is whatever your path from the root is
    : '/'
}
```

You can read more about `publicPath` [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

Make sure your `.htaccess` is in */docs/1.0/* as well

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing to a different port than whatever port it runs on by default.

For example, if the default port is localhost:8080, then try

```
npm run serve -- --port 8085
```

It's the quickest fix I've found.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you forget to include the `()` after `createWebHistory`